# Android phonegap word cut in the label

Tags: html, label

Hai i hava a Application in PhoneGap ,for designing i used html.i have a problem in label,When text is long the word is cut down.

i used word wrap to break the word

My code http://jsfiddle.net/elakkiya/fvNte/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the height:30px; attribute and make sure to close both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/fvNte/1/

**Update:** The problem was that you set the height to smaller than the container so the browser complied. You could either write overflow:hidden; so that it stays the size you wants but shows no text outside the area you designated or you can

1)Set no height
2)Or set a minimum height (min-height:30px;)